# Call iOS application via Custom URL Scheme

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, launch, url-scheme

I'm developing a native iOS application and in my Info.plist.xml I got:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
     <dict>
       <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>digitalsigner.com</string>
       <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>http</key>
            </array>
     </dict>
  </array>
```

When I call in iOS Simulator's Safari: http://digitalsigner.com or if I open an html page with link to http://digitalsigner.com my app isn't launched.

What am I doing wrong, or what's missing?

Thank you,
Best Regards,
William.

Answer (score 2):

If more than one application registers for a URL scheme, the system behavior is undefined. Since the system default for http is definitely registered with Safari, I wouldn't put much stock in being able to use that for your own app.

> Apple provides built-in support for the http, mailto, tel, and sms URL schemes. It also supports http–based URLs targeted at the Maps, YouTube, and iPod apps. The handlers for these schemes are fixed and cannot be changed. If your URL type includes a scheme that is identical to one defined by Apple, the Apple-provided app is launched instead of your app.
>   Note: If more than one third-party app registers to handle the same URL scheme, there is currently no process for determining which app will be given that scheme.

Comment: Thank you all. I've already change the CFBundleURLSchemes to other word and it worked :) Just one more thing, if I have a URL Scheme like anything://digitalsigner.com?link="anyothersite.com/abc.pdf"; how do I get the link value? I know it is something related with NSDicitonary, but what's the appropriated method? Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple docs, if there are multiple applications registered for the same URL scheme then there's no guarantees as to which app will receive the request. I strongly believe that MobileSafari   already registered for `http` scheme, so this is why your app is not launched.

Comment: Thank you all. I've already change the CFBundleURLSchemes to other word and it worked :) Just one more thing, if I have a URL Scheme like anything://digitalsigner.com?link="anyothersite.com/abc.pdf"; how do I get the link value? I know it is something related with NSDicitonary, but what's the appropriated method? Thank you once again.

Comment: To get query string (everything after `?`) you can use `yourUrl.query` property.  To convert that into a `NSDictionary` you can use code from e.g. https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSDictionary%2BURLArguments.m. You will then be able to access link value via `NSDictionary* theDict = [url.query gtm_dictionaryWithHttpArgumentsString]; DoSomethingWithLink(theDict[@"link"]);`. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Custom URL Scheme is a "prefix" of address, like protocol type - for example, "http://", "fb://", @"tel://".
In your case URL scheme is @"http://" or @"https://". For these schemes system already has registered application.
Sorry, but you can't do what you want for all cases.

Comment: Thank you all. I've already change the CFBundleURLSchemes to other word and it worked :) Just one more thing, if I have a URL Scheme like anything://digitalsigner.com?link="anyothersite.com/abc.pdf"; how do I get the link value? I know it is something related with NSDicitonary, but what's the appropriated method? Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

try to enter this url  `digitalsigner.com://`

it's works for me

Comment: Thank you all. I've already change the CFBundleURLSchemes to other word and it worked :)
Just one more thing, if I have a URL Scheme like anything://digitalsigner.com?link="http://anyothersite.com/abc.pdf" how do I get the link value? I know it is something related with NSDicitonary, but what's the appropriated method?

Thank you once again.